# How are these two definitions of energy related/derive from each other?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, mass, mass-energy

How are these two definitions of energy related/derive from each other:

$$E = \frac{mc^2} {\sqrt{(1 - v^2/c^2)}}$$

vs.

$$E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2c^2}~?$$

Both equations express the relation between invariant/rest mass and energy. Can you express one from the other?

Comment: Well what have you tried in relating the two yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A derivation is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation#Heuristic_approach_for_massive_particles) on Wikipedia.

Starting with
$$E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2c^2}$$
we plug in the [formula for relativistic momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Relativistic)
$$p = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
to obtain
$$E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + \frac{m^2v^2c^2}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}=mc^2\sqrt{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2-v^2}}=mc^2\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^2-v^2}}=mc^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
$$=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
which is your first formula.

Comment: Thanks! The relativistic momentum is what I was missing. This helped.

Answer (score 1):

$\let\g=\gamma \let\De=\Delta \def\D#1#2{{d#1 \over d#2}}$
Consider the following four equations (I take for granted that the
meaning of $\g$ as a function of $v$ is well known).
$$E = m\,c^2 \g \tag1$$
$$p = m\,v\,\g \tag2$$
$$c^2 p = v\,E \tag3$$
$$E = c\,\sqrt{m^2 c^2 + p^2}.\tag4$$
Starting from any couple of them you can easily derive the remainig
two.

So your question has no answer. It all depends on the approach we
choose to SR. For instance I could

1) Show that between two events $\De x^2 - c^2 \De t^2$ is invariant.

2) Define proper time $\De\tau$ by
$$\De\tau^2 = \De t^2 - \De x^2/c^2.\tag5$$

3) Define, for a moving point, mass as an invariant quantity, measured
in its rest frame.

4) Then define
$$E = m\,c^2 \D t\tau \qquad p = m\,c\,\D x\tau.\tag6$$

5) Use (5) and (6) to prove (4) and deduce (3) from (6). Then (1) and (2) follow.

It remains to find the physical meaning of $E$, $p$ so defined. But
here I would stop. I hope you don't expect a full treatment of
relativistic dynamics$\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that
$$E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2c^2}\qquad \mbox{in the OP and in @Elio's (4)}$$
and
$$p = vE/c^2\qquad\mbox{in @Elio's (3)}$$
are more fundamental

 
than either
$\quad \displaystyle E = \frac{mc^2} {\sqrt{(1 - v^2/c^2)}} \quad$ or 
$\quad\displaystyle  p = \frac{mv} {\sqrt{(1 - v^2/c^2)}}\quad$ (see the OP and @Elio's (1) and (2)).

---

When $m\neq 0$, then
@Glorfindel's proof goes through.


But this might look better...
 Substituting $\quad p=vE/c^2$
$$E^2 = {m^2c^4 + \left(\frac{v}{c^2}E\right)^2c^2}\quad
={m^2c^4 + \left(\frac{v^2}{c^2}E^2\right)}
$$
So that
$$E^2 \left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)= {m^2c^4}\quad
$$
However, when $m=0$, this last equation implies that
either

- $E=0$ (uninteresting) or
- $|v|=c$ (with $E\neq 0$)...
  but then this equation won't let us solve for $E$.

When $m=0$ or $|v|=c$, we find that the fundamental equations reduce to:
$$E = pc,$$
which is not generally zero.

Indeed, in spite of a photon having zero rest mass, 
it generally has [nonzero] energy and momentum.